# Is css preventing list rendering?

Tags: css, list, django-templates

Good evening. I'm trying to make a site with Django. Not being expert in CSS I took a template  (minimaxing, from html5up.net). Everything works fine, as you can see (http://secret-reaches-8428.herokuapp.com/lesson/lezioneA00/) except that ordered and unordered list are not rendered as such. I can guess is something in the css, but I can't see where the problem is. There are the three .css files loaded in the header:

- http://secret-reaches-8428.herokuapp.com/static/css/style.css
- //same_domain/style-desktop.css
- //same_domain/style.css

Question is: can anybody point out what part of the css is to be modified or, can anybody point out what the problem is?

---

Ok, I solved looking for standard css attributes and setting up  properties as I wanted. Now I'm just curious to understand why the normal html behavior was overwritten, since there is no reference to  in the css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your img sources. You have a problem with your `img` sources, not with your `ul` or `ol` rendering.

You try to reach an image [here](http://secret-reaches-8428.herokuapp.com/lesson/lezioneA00/images/pic2.jpg/), but it does not exist. Try to fix the URL reference.

Comment: My fault, I have posted a misleading example. The list I was referring was the one without class attribute, the one on the left. The one that does not look like a list: a paragraph with less interline perhaps. Anyway, I solved somehow, but still don't know why there was a problem.